# How to change the direction of a GradientPaint?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d, linear-gradients

I am trying to draw a gradient rectangle that goes from red to blue. I have the following code:

```
g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.RED, 1000, 1000, Color.BLUE));
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

This is working. However, the direction of the gradient is diagonal, from the top left point of the rectangle to the bottom right point (another way to look at this is that the gradient follows the line of  `y=-x + windowHeight`)

I would like my gradient to go from top to bottom. So the entire top of the rectangle is red, and the entire bottom is blue. In other words, the color should only change with the y coordinate, given any y=point line the color should be uniform across that line.

I have included the following images also to give a general idea of what I am trying to do: [image]

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all has to do with the vector of your gradient. Here: `(0, 0, Color.RED, 1000, 1000, Color.BLUE)` you're vector is a diagonal vector that originates at [0, 0], and then ends or points at [1000, 1000] or on a 45 degree angle.

Change that to straight down:  [0, 0] going to [0, 1000] should work well. e.g,

```
new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.RED, 0, 1000, Color.BLUE)
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked great. Seems obvious in hindsight, I guess the part that was confusing me was the behavior of the gradients once they went over their specified range, now I know: they repeat. Thanks!